# sql syntax how to do a join?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql

Im trying to retrieve a path name from my Pictures table the pathname is stored under picturepath in my Pictures table I dont know how to join it on to my current sql syntax it uses the UserID which is set by a session.

And im unsure what goes in the commented line for my image url string?

```
    using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT Wallpostings FROM WallPosting WHERE UserID=" + userId + " ORDER BY idWallPosting DESC", cn))
    {
        using (OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            test1.Controls.Clear();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
                div.Attributes["class"] = "test";
        //div.Style["float"] = "left";

                div.ID = "test";
                Image img = new Image();
                img.ImageUrl = String.Format("{unsure}", reader.GetString(unsure));
                // this line needs to be represented in sql syntax
                img.AlternateText = "Test image";

                div.Controls.Add(img);
                div.Controls.Add(ParseControl(String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0))));
                div.Style["clear"] = "both";
                test1.Controls.Add(div);
```

[image]

Comment: Just a note... if this is how you typically call the database, my guess would be that you're wide open to a SQL injection attack.

Comment: Agreed - I've recommended against this method in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
img.ImageUrl = string.Format("~/userdata/2/uploadedimage/{0}", (string)reader["TheImageColumn"]);
```

This will pull the `TheImageColumn` field from the reader and insert it where `{0}` is in the string.

#### SQL

```
SELECT
    wp.WallPostings,
    p.PicturePath
FROM
    WallPosting wp
    LEFT JOIN [User] u ON u.UserID = wp.UserID
    LEFT JOIN Pictures p ON p.UserID = u.UserID
WHERE UserID = @UserID
ORDER BY idWallPosting DESC
```

You should also not in-line your parameters, use `cmd.AddParameter()` instead.

Comment: I think my code is correct I just need to set it to 1 and 0 but its my sql syntax to take the (full) pathname from Pictures picturepath

Comment: You're looking to pull back the entire URL in the SELECT statement? If yes, why? (That seems weird.)

Comment: well its only a case of select picturepath from Pictures I just dont know how to join it to my existing sql syntax

Comment: It's fairly unclear what you really mean. I updated my answer but not sure it's what you're asking.

Comment: hey your sqlsyntax is nice I shall give this a try but im sorry I left a comment in my code with a url please ignore this I was wondering why you were setting this in your code, thought you were physcic for a moment. I will like the values I set as Unsure in my image url to be 1 then 0 but im unsure if this is correct?